# How to query ADFS repository for authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, authentication, webforms, adfs

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application and ADFS correctly implemented.

I successfully use ADFS for SSO in many applications but now I need to use the ADFS repository just to validate login credentials on-premises, not for the login itself.

My application is a simple form with Textboxes for username and password and a Login button. Once the user inserts username and password and clicks on login I need to check with ADFS whether the data are correct, receive the response and based on that perform some other task.

In the SSO I already implemented it is the STS itself that displays the pop-up for login credentials but in this case I want this task to be fulfilled by my app.

Anybody might tell me if that is possible and point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to have your own login form in a web app? That doesn't sound fair, if the ADFS is further federated with other identity providers, your check could just miss that.

Having said that, if you really want this, you should enable a `usernamemixed` endpoint endpoint in the ADFS configuration, configure your application as a relying party and request a token:

```
string stsEndpoint = "https://WIN-2013.win2008.marz.com/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed";
string relyingPartyUri = "https://www.yourrelyingpartyuri.com";

WSTrustChannelFactory factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
new EndpointAddress(stsEndpoint));

factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;

// Username and Password here...
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "remote_user01";
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "the_password";

RequestSecurityToken rst = new RequestSecurityToken
{
   RequestType = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrust13Constants.RequestTypes.Issue,
   AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress(relyingPartyUri),
   KeyType = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrust13Constants.KeyTypes.Bearer,
};

IWSTrustChannelContract channel = factory.CreateChannel();

SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst);

//if authentication is failed, exception will be thrown. Error is inside the innerexception.
//Console.WriteLine("Token Id: " + token.Id);
```

This particular snippet is copied from this blog entry:

http://leandrob.com/2012/04/requesting-a-token-from-adfs-2-0-using-ws-trust-with-username-and-password/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Regarding your remark on implementing the login in a web app, I explain better my scenario. I have a cloud based web app that gives the opportunity to implement SSO but it does not use ADFS, which is the repository I use to store my users' data. Therefore, they cannot redirect the request directly in my STS endpoint. In order to validate the login the response needs to be redirected to one bridge web application, the one that I am building, which then validates the login within my domain by using ADFS and eventually send the SSO token to the requesting web app :)

Comment: Another way to setup your environment would be to have a WCF servive guarded with federated active authentication. This way, invoking the service would require passing the username/password pair and the federated binding would automatically go to ADFS for a token on behalf of the user. An advantage of this flow would be that the user asks the app's webservice which then asks the ADFS by itself. The user never contacts the ADFS directly. The active WCF federated binding can be set up according to the documentation.

Comment: Yeah your solution is the most logic indeed but the third party that provides the cloud based mobile app does not provide the possibility to communicate with a WS, they explicitly require a web application. Which indeed acts basically as a WS but I have no control for that ;-)